# Get IMG link from DIV returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the IMG address from a DIV in HTML page. 
When I call

```
document.getElementById('m-person--image l-person--image')
```

It returns NULL.

Here is the HTML page I try to perform this action:
https://www.biography.com/business-figure/tim-cook

I tried to extract the image address of Tim Cook. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: A class (or as in this case a list of classes) is not an id - hence it's `class="..."` and not `id="..."` in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page, that you provided, `m-person--image` and `l-person--image` are classes on the `div` that wraps image element, and not an id.
You can get this image element by classes with the `querySelector` function:

```js
document.querySelector('.m-person--image.l-person--image > img');
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. Such a clean and complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName('m-person--image')

Answer (score 0):

This way works great

```
document.querySelector('img[alt="Tim Cook"').src
```

Comment: This will always throw a `TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `id`, but the div you are looking for is identified by `class`

```
<div class="m-person--image l-person--image">
<img src="https://www.biography.com/.image/ar_1:1%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cg_face%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_300/MTE5NDg0MDU1MzM0OTc5MDg3/tim-cook-20967297-1-402.jpg" alt="Tim Cook" itemprop="image" nopin="true" data-pin-no-hover="true">
</div>
```

Use `getElementsByClassName`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('m-person--image l-person--image')
```